# How to prove that if a line is perpendicular to the radius of a circle at its endpoint of the circle, it must be tangent to the circle.

Tags: geometry

I have seen proofs for proving if a line is tangent to the circle, then it has to be perpendicular to the radius of the circle. But I want to know how you can prove the other direction of this statement since this is biconditional statement. Start with the hypothesis that some line is perpendicular to the radius of the circle, then prove it must be a tangent line to the circle.

If I were to use the proof by contradiction, do I have to consider the case where the line intersects the circle at two points as well as the case when the line is not meeting the circle at all?

Comment: The line has to be perpendicular to the radius at a specific point. If I vary this point, the line can lie anywhere. Once you fix "perpendicular at a point on the circle", then for contradiction, you must consider the case when the line intersects at two points (for it must intersect at one point,  where both are perpendicular).

Comment: This is not true. You can have a line perpendicular to the radius thats inside the circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hypothesis should be that line $t$ is perpendicular to the radius $OT$ at point $T$ on the circle of center $O$. In that case, if $P$ is another point on $t$, different from $T$, then we have $OP>OT$ (hypotenuse is greater then leg). It follows that all points of $t$, except $T$, are external to the circle, and $t$ is thus a tangent.